# Objective C - Using typedef struct in header file

Tags: objective-c, c, linked-list

I am trying to create a LinkedList in Objective C.

In the .h file I am trying to create a Node using the code:

```
@interface AALinkedList : NSObject
{
    typedef struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
    } Node;
}
```

This gives me an error saying `Type name does not allow storage class to be specified`

What does this mean ? and how do I fix it ?

Comment: You cannot define a new type in Objective-C class's data section. `storage class` is about `typedef`, as it is a storage class just like `static` or `auto`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
} Node;

@interface AALinkedList : NSObject
{
    Node node;
    // or Node *node;
}
```

Comment: Why does it go above the @interface ?

Comment: Because `@interface {` is almost the same as `struct {`, and you do not define new types in a struct body. Even if you were able, this is pointless, because scope of the name would be limited to just that struct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a typedef in the .h file. Declare it in the .m. That should get you going.Put the method signature on the .h

You can create a simple LinkedList Class like this.

```
@interface LinkedNode : NSObject 
  @property (nonatomic, strong) id nextNode;
@end
then you use it as you would expect:

id currentNode = myFirstNode;
do {
  [currentNode someMessage];
}
while(currentNode = currentNode.nextNode);
```

Comment: why ? and where in the .m file ?

Comment: This is not true, you can declare it *in the correct place* in either the .h or .m file. Using a property is better than a struct though.